# Is there a benefit of using EXPECT_NO_THROW in Google test?

Tags: googletest

In gtest one can use the EXPECT_NO_THROW macro to verify that an action does not throw an exception.

When the code does throw an exception, the test case will be marked as failed.
However, if the EXPECT_NO_THROW macro is *not* used and an exception is thrown, the test case will fail too.

As far as I can observe the following are functionally equivalent:

```
sut.do_action();
```

```
EXPECT_NO_THROW(sut.do_action());
```

So, is there any benefit or reason to use EXPECT_NO_THROW? Or is its only purpose to make the test case specification more explicit?

Comment: Does other testscases execute if you do not add EXPECT_NO_THROW?

Comment: @AlbinPaul: yes, the test will mark the test case where the exception was thrown as failed, but it will still continue with any remaining test cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's so obvious.

1. It gives you ability to output something if an exception thrown

   ```
   EXPECT_NO_THROW(sut.do_action()) << "Must not throw";
   ```
2. It allows a test case to continue after an exception is thrown

   ```
   sut.do_action();
   std::cout << "Continue\n";  // does not output
   ```

   ```
   EXPECT_NO_THROW(sut.do_action());
   std::cout << "Continue\n";  // outputs regardless of an exception
   ```

Comment: Only after reading your answer did I realize there must also be a ASSERT_NO_THROW.